# Simple Cucumber Test Class Passes with no Glue File

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

This has been puzzling me for half a day now. I can't seem to find the issue. Basically I have my Test runner, feature file, and the steps file in my workspace. The java files are in the same package (i.e. no package).

Below is my `TestRunner.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "test/resources/features", tags = { "~@Ignore" })
public class TestRunner {

    @Test
    public void feature() {
    }
}
```

My feature file, `helloWorld.feature`

```
Feature: Simple Test Feature

Scenario: Run Scenario ONE
GIVEN step one
WHEN step two
THEN step three
```

and my steps file `CucumberJava.java`,

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class CucumberJava {

    @Given("^step one$")
    public void step_one() {

        System.out.println("step one");
    }

    @When("step two")
    public void step_two() {
        System.out.println("step two");
    }

    @Then("^step three$")
    public void step_three() {
        System.out.println("step three");
    }
}
```

When I execute `TestRunner.java` as JUnit, everything passes, but I get the following in the console:

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

WHY? In fact, when I remove `CucumberJava.java` from the project, I get the exact same output. What am I missing? 
I also tried setting the `glue` option in `TestRunner.java` code too; still the same result.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature file words like Given etc are in uppercase in your feature file. They need to be like Given ie sentence case.

```
Feature: Simple Test Feature

Scenario: Run Scenario ONE
Given step one
When step two
Then step three
```

Also you might need to append a 'src' to the feature path in the runner. Like this `features = "src/test/resources/features"`, if you are using Maven. Also no need to have a `@Test annotation and method` inside the runner.

Comment: the casing of `Given`, `When`, `Then` fixed the issue .. thank you